# Gracenote API: Fetching Images

Tags: api, gracenote

I have a few questions related to images in gracenote API.
Let's take this image for example: http://akamai-b.cdn.cddbp.net/cds/2.0/image/5899/C629/E091/E3A2_medium_front.jpg

After trying to manipulate a bit the image name, i found that i could get another format for the same image: small.
Is there somewhere in gracenote documentation where i can get list of possible image formats ?

Another thing that i noticed in image name is "front".
Does that mean that there are other images for the same content that we can get ?

Thanks to anyone who can help me about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find options for image sizes in the eyeQ Web API Reference Documentation https://developer.gracenote.com/sites/default/files/eyeq-webapi-ref.pdf

The image sizes available are

THUMBNAIL (75)
SMALL (170)
MEDIUM (450)
LARGE (720)
XLARGE (1080)

(Note, all dimensions are max size - some images are not square)

You can select one or more image sizes through the IMAGE_SIZE option, e.g.:

```
<OPTION>
    <PARAMETER>IMAGE_SIZE</PARAMETER>
    <VALUE>XLARGE,SMALL</VALUE>
</OPTION>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image format is .jpg but I assume you are asking about image sizes.
There are at most 5 sizes available: thumbnail, small, medium (default), large, xlarge.
Also there is only one image returned per content.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Do you know if this information is available somewhere in gracenote documentation ?

Comment: I just would like to adjust the given response.
actualy you can get multiple images for an av_work by using the following option:
<OPTION>
 <PARAMETER>SELECT_EXTENDED</PARAMETER>
 <VALUE>IMAGE,CONTRIBUTOR_IMAGE,IMAGE_GALLERY</VALUE>
 </OPTION>